# void function returns none value

Tags: c

I met this:

```
static void foo (ui32_t val)
{
   if (condition)
   {
      return;
   }
   .......
   .......
}
```

I don't understand how void function would have return in it, and how return don't return anything?
What is the purpose of return nothing and when do we use it? Thank you guys!

Comment: It returns nothing, but it ends the function <-!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just exists the function. It's useful if you want to abort the execution of the rest of the function at some point.

```
static void foo (uint32_t val)
{
   if (condition)
   {
      /* cancel the execution of the rest of the function */
      return;
   }
   thisLineWill_NOT_BeReachedIfConditionIsTrue();
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't return anything, `return;` simply terminates the function.

You use it when you don't want to execute a block depending on some condition and terminate the function.

If there was no `return;`, control returns to the calling function after executing the *last* statement of the function.

Comment: Upvoted for saying it doesn't return anything - which is arguably different from returning nothing.